# Decimal keypad Xcode

Tags: xcode4.6

I have a text box and a calculate button, I am using a Decimal keypad, when I run my program in the Xcode simulator i get a dot at the bottom left corner but when I run the program in my iPhone i get a comma in the bottom left corner.  I know the simulator is set on US Locale and I am in Iceland, I don't get the same outcome if I use the comma instead of the dot.  I need to use the dot in my text box, not comma.  Is there any code that I can use that tell my program to use dot instead of comma or do I need to make a custom keyboard for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you're after. If you want to change the way the keyboard looks, then you have to write your own keyboard. But if it is sufficient to respond to the comma by putting a dot in the text field, you can do that easily by intercepting the comma in the text field's delegate. Implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`. Something like this (not tested so you might need to tweak it some):

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
        shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
        replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (![string isEqualToString: @","])
        return YES;
    textField.text =
        [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                withString: @"."];
    return NO;
}
```

If the problem is that the comma is okay, but in countries where the comma is the decimal point, you want it to be used as a decimal point, just use an NSNumberFormatter when you pull the string out of the text field and turn it into a number. Right now you are doing this by saying `[_PipeID.text floatValue]`. That call has no intelligence about the locale. NSNumberFormatter does:

```
NSNumberFormatter* nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
nf.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSNumber* n = [nf numberFromString: tf.text];
// and *then* you can convert the NSNumber to a float with `floatValue`
NSLog(@"%f",n.floatValue);
```

By the way, you said:

> when I run my program in the Xcode simulator ... but when I run the program in my iPhone

But you can test this perfectly well on the Simulator; just use the Settings app to set the language and region formatting.

Comment: Ok, if I put 2.5 in the text box that number is supposed to multiply with it self and I will get 6.25(that is what I want) but if I put 2,5 I will get 4 because if I use comma the 2,5 will go down to 2 and the outcome will be 4, hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Oh. Well you just need to use an NSNumberFormatter to derive the numeric value from the text string in accordance with the locale.

Comment: Thank you for the code but I am new in programming, can you please tell me where exactly to put this code :)

Comment: Pls edit your answer to show the code you are using to pull the value out of the text field and turn it into a number.

Comment: - (IBAction)Calculate:(id)sender {
    
    float a = ([_PipeID.text floatValue]);
    float b = 1029.4;
    float c = a * a;
    
    _PipeID.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%.2f",a * a];
    _Total.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%.6f",c / b];

Comment: Hope you can read this, I don´t know how to put the code in like you do

Comment: Thank you for all your help Matt, I have been playing with this for 2 hours now and no luck, is it possible to send you email for more help, this comment box is to short :)  This is my email if you could help me out, trausig@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

```
float s2 = [[dist.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."] floatValue];

dist.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%0.02f", s2];
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me alot .